# Trigger Azure Function once on bulk upload

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have a Azure function that I want to trigger when I upload multiple images at once. The problem is that the blob trigger triggers on upload of individual files. Which means my function triggers for the x amount of files that I upload in that chunk. I would like to only trigger my function one time per bulk upload.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Best Regards,
R

Comment: The trigger doesn't know when the last file is uploaded because though it is a bulk upload for you, it's still just a collection of individual files. Perhaps you could upload a sort of manifest file after each bulk upload and have the trigger based on that?

Comment: Yeah indeed, that's actually exactly what I did as a work around. I added a trigger.txt file and trigger the function on blob upload with file format .txt. I then add a time sleep in the code since the .txt file uploads really quickly(waiting for all the images to be uploaded). Just thought there would be a cleaner way to achieve this! Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @reduards please could you elaborate on this for me. I want to trigger the event based from ADF only when all the files are uploaded, so where do I keep this manifest file. And what’s the configuration.

Comment: In my case, it’s not always bulk upload but it needs to know when the upload is done and starts the trigger

Answer (score 1):

[reduards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16775350/reduards) Glad to hear that you resolved your issue.
Thank you [joelforsyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3680190/joelforsyth) Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> "The trigger doesn't know when the last file is uploaded because
> though it is a bulk upload for you, it's still just a collection of
> individual files.  You can upload a sort of manifest file after each
> bulk upload and have the trigger based on that"